# Which contract's storage does SLOAD/SSTORE use?

Tags: storage, opcode, trace

A given `SSTORE` and `SLOAD` instruction uses storage from a certain smart contract. How can we know which contract that is, and do we need any additional data than the raw struct/opcode traces to find out?

I'm looking at raw opcode/struct traces along with call traces, and checking with state storage diffs, and it appears to me that it inside a given call, that a storage opcode uses the storage of the `to` contract. Is that correct?

Comment: Despite the transaction type(internal or non-internal), all executions are done with regards to the "to contract", or is it not?

Comment: I don't know! That's why I'm asking. But that's helpful, thanks!